# How to extract exact frequencies from signal?

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft

I have a 1D signal array. This array holds information about some features that I want to analyze with `np.fft`.

As an example I tried the following:

My function should be the simple sine wave `lambda x : sin(x)`, in theory when I put an input array through this function I would get a signal array, which when transformed with an fft should tell me that the main component from that signal was (in pseudocode) `signal = 1* sin(x)`.

So far I couldnt get any wiser from any of the answers here so I put this question up.

Now my question: How do I get the "raw" sine component weights from my signal ?

This is where I'm stuck:

```
>>> y = f(x)
>>> fqs = np.fft.fft(y)
>>> fqs
array([ 3.07768354+0.00000000e+00j,  3.68364588+8.32272378e-16j,
        8.73514635-7.15951776e-15j, -7.34287625+1.04901868e-14j,
       -2.15156054+5.10742080e-15j, -1.1755705 +4.87611209e-16j,
       -0.78767676+3.40334406e-16j, -0.58990993+4.25167217e-16j,
       -0.476018  -3.43242308e-16j, -0.40636656+1.13055751e-15j,
       -0.36327126+1.55440604e-16j, -0.33804202-1.07128132e-16j,
       -0.32634218+2.76861429e-16j, -0.32634218+8.99298797e-16j,
       -0.33804202+5.02435797e-16j, -0.36327126-1.55440604e-16j,
       -0.40636656-3.06536611e-16j, -0.476018  -4.57882679e-17j,
       -0.58990993+4.31587904e-16j, -0.78767676+9.75500354e-16j,
       -1.1755705 -4.87611209e-16j, -2.15156054-1.87113952e-15j,
       -7.34287625+1.79193327e-15j,  8.73514635-6.76648711e-15j,
        3.68364588-6.60371698e-15j])
>>> np.abs(_)
array([3.07768354, 3.68364588, 8.73514635, 7.34287625, 2.15156054,
       1.1755705 , 0.78767676, 0.58990993, 0.476018  , 0.40636656,
       0.36327126, 0.33804202, 0.32634218, 0.32634218, 0.33804202,
       0.36327126, 0.40636656, 0.476018  , 0.58990993, 0.78767676,
       1.1755705 , 2.15156054, 7.34287625, 8.73514635, 3.68364588])
>>> where do I find my 1*sin(x) ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though your `x` variable is know shown here, I think you're not generating a periodic function. This works fine for me:

```
import numpy as np
x=np.linspace(0,np.pi*2,100,endpoint=False)
y=np.sin(x)
yf=np.fft.rfft(y)
```

output is

```
 (-1.5265566588595902e-16+0.0j)
 (-1.8485213360008856e-14+-50.0j)
 (5.8988036787285649e-15+-3.4015634637549994e-16j)
 (-1.0781745022416177e-14+-3.176912458933349e-15j)
 (6.9770353907875146e-15+-3.6920723832369405e-15j)
```

The only no zero imaginary number is at mode 1.

Comment: so the imaginary unit determines the "power" of that signal ?
also am I correct to assume that the i-th value of `yf` corresponds to the ith "sum term" ? 
also do I need to take the absolute value of that array to get the sine components ?
sorry for asking so much, if you'd link me a good resource I'd read that first and then ask

Comment: This is basic Fourier analysis so even wikipedia should work. If the function was cos(x) then the real part would have had the value. It's cos(nx)+isin(nx).
Also don't forget to accept the answer as solution.